# Can anyone help me view textbox (multi-line textmode) in gridview with exactly the same format

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, multiline

having a problem again... i found a code, but it doesn't work with me... and can't find any related topic here... so then i ask... can anyone do this?

see this link for the image... [Please help me do this...](http://public.dm2301.livefilestore.com/y2ppVPG_IK7bQrSPwMeWfS0WBrWHHkgmhpnItlMX-LBMYiUWZLLSyhccTC_ypfU-EvqIwKK3J_WWL4ejfnPn39LbxO5F98sLFRitWBu5zx5mcI/Richtextboxanimation.Gif?psid=1&rdrts=74757871)

here is our c# code to add and view it on the GridView asp.net

```
public partial class parypackage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection PartyConnection = new SqlConnection();
    DataSet partyDataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter partySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    private string connect;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PartyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        PartyConnection = new SqlConnection(connect);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridview();
        }
    }

    protected void BindGridview()
    {
        PartyConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from package", PartyConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PartyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        PartyConnection = new SqlConnection(connect);
        PartyConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand addCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT package (pkgnumber,pkgitems,pkgamount) values ('" + Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) + "',@Richtextbox ,'" + Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text) + "')", PartyConnection);
        SqlDataReader partySqlDataReader;
        addCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Richtextbox", TextBox2.Text);
        partySqlDataReader = addCommand.ExecuteReader();
        partySqlDataReader.Close();
        PartyConnection.Close();
        BindGridview();
        Response.Redirect("partypackage.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: we don't use any of the freetextbox or FTB... we only use the free-defined textbox of the application... and the textmode is multiline so we can use the enter key for inserting a new line

Comment: for another explanation... we only need to view the saved data showing the new line in the gridview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cant do this with a multi-line textbox. Although you may try some workarounds but it will be too difficult to have the desired result. A textbox captures the plain text inputted to it. Basically, this is the job of text editor to present the user with styling facilities and capturing the data inputted in form of HTML markup. I strongly recommend to use any free text editor instead of a multiline textbox to achieve this easily.